# If the diagonal of a rectangular box measures L, then what is its maximum volume?

Tags: geometry, volume, means

> If the diagonal of a rectangular box measures L, then what is its maximum volume ( in terms of L ) ?

$L = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$, then $L^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.

By AM-GM, $$L^2 \ge 3V^{\frac{2}{3}}$$.

Therefore the maximum volume is $ V = \frac{L^2}{3}\sqrt\frac{L^2}{3}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, and that's when it will be a cube